# doing a backup before reset in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this record :

```
-record(person, {id, token, password, pin, key, salt, pin_salt, subscription_date, first_name, last_name, alias, gender, created_at, birth_year, birth_month, birth_date}).
```

and I have this function which create the table **person_backup**

```
testcreate()->      

    mnesia:create_table(person_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]).
```

and I have this function which transfert data from table person to person_backup

```
testbackup()->

    mnesia:transaction(fun() ->
  Records = mnesia:select(person, [{'_', [], ['$_']}]),
  [ok = mnesia:write(person_backup, Record, write) || Record <- Records]
end).
```

my goal is to do a test in my principal function

```
check(Counter)->

if Counter =:= 40 ->
model:testbackup();
model:reset():
true-> io:format(" it not ok")
end.
```

but my problem  is when I do :model:reset()

**the table person_backup will be deleted**

and my goal is before doing model:reset() we should transfer data from person to person_backup

this is a code of **reset() , destroy(), create()**

```
reset() ->
    stop(),
    destroy(),
    create(),
    start(),

    {ok}.


destroy() ->
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:delete_table(counter),
    mnesia:delete_table(person),
    mnesia:stop(),
    mnesia:delete_schema([node()]).


create() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),
    mnesia:create_table(counter, [{attributes, record_info(fields, counter)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
    mnesia:create_table(person, [{attributes, record_info(fields, person)}, {disc_copies, [node()]}]),
  mnesia:create_table(person_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
    {record_name, person}]),
    mnesia:stop().
```

Answer (score 1):

When you delete schema all the tables will be deleted including your person_backup. Do not do delete_schema in destroy and everything will work fine.

Better would be that make your creation of tables separate and reset separate. In reset you can do mnesia:clear_table of person and counter instead. I am wondering why you need to restart mnesia.

Comment: but when I eliminate mnesia:delete_schema([node()]) from destroy all the data from all table are not deleted

Comment: that is why you should not delete your schema as person_backup also gets deleted. You need to do clear_table for all those tables for which data needs to be cleared. Or other way would be to create a schema in different node and have your person_backup there.